# Unique ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R_{\infty}:=\mathbb{Z}[[x_{ij}|1\leq i <j\leq \infty]]$ be the ring of formal power series in infinitely many variables with polynomial-like addition and multiplication and only finite products allowed. Also, given some $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 3}$, let $R_m:=\mathbb{Z}[[x_{ij}|1\leq i < j \leq m]]$ be a ring of formal power series with obvious addition and multiplication and, again, only finite products allowed. One possible ring homomorphism from $R_{\infty}$ to $R_m$ can be defined by sending $x_{ij}$ to itself if $j \leq m$ and to $0$, else (and extending algebraically). I tried to come up with a different ring homomorphism but I haven't been able to (it is always has been the homomorphism thing that breaks). It made me wonder if it was me missing something or if that is the only possible ring homomorphism (going in that particular direction) between those two rings. Every hint is much appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of small modifications you can make. You can permute a finite subset of the variables, you can scale the variables, you can apply a matrix to a finite subset of the variables, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. Seems like I was blinded by trying to show that a certain diagram involving the objects in the question commutes and ended up missing the obvious.

Comment: I think you also need to be a bit more careful what you mean by formal power series in infinitely many variables, especially without picking an order on the indices. E.g. is $x_{11} + x_{22} + x_{33} + \dots$ an element?

Comment: It is not an element. I set it (the ring) up in the following way. Let $\alpha:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ be s.t. $\alpha(i,j)=0$ when $i \geq j$ and $\alpha(i,j) \neq 0$ finitely many times. Then an arbitrary element of $R_{\infty}$ can be written as $\displaystyle \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}$ with no restrictions on $c_{\alpha} \in \mathbb{Z}$.